# How to disable ZK CKeditor Component

Tags: ckeditor, zk

The latest version of ZK CKEditor (org.zkoss.zkforge:ckez:4.7.0.0) doesn't provide a straightfoward method to disable the component whereas the original CKEditor provides a [Read Only mode](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/features/readonly.html) through Javascript. Usually, a normal ZK component offers the [disabled](https://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zul/impl/InputElement.html#setDisabled-boolean-) attribute so the user cannot change the input state via UI.

How can I disable ZK's CKEditor component without having the disabled attribute available?

my.zul:

```xml
<ckeditor id="myCKComponentId"/> <!-- disabled doesn't exist -->
```

MyComposer.java:

```java
public class MyComposer extends GenericForwardComposer {
    CKeditor myCKComponentId;

    public void doAfterCompose(Component comp) throws Exception {
        super.doAfterCompose(comp);
        myCKComponentId.setDisabled(true); // <--- Doesn't exist
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory, the `disabled` attribute should've been provided for the CKeditor component as it should be considered to be the same as any other input, but **it's possible to achieve the same result by passing the config Map with a `readOnly` key/value, which will change the settings for the component without the need to use Javascript directly**:

```java
myCKComponentId.setConfig(new HashMap<String, Object>() {{ put("readOnly", true); }});
```

Java 8 and above (one line)

```java
myCKComponentId.setConfig(Map.of("readOnly", true));
```

Using Javascript:

```js
zk.Widget.$(jq('$myCKComponentId')).getEditor().setReadOnly(true);
```